# isalpha() and isascii() with parentheses causing errors, but not without

Tags: python

What is the objective of these parentheses and why are the errors occurring ?

This is the error I receive when an ASCII character is typed with the parentheses after `a.isalpha` and `a.isascii`:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/---/---/PycharmProjects/PythonExercicios/test.py", line 4, in 
>       a1 = float(a)
>   ValueError: could not convert string to float: '!'

```
a = str(input('Type the "a" side of the triangle: ')).strip()
while a.isascii() and a.isalpha():
    a = input('Please, type again using only numbers: ')
a1 = float(a)
```

Comment: One can type the alphabet, how can it be cast into `float`? The last statement.

Comment: @Lamanus If they typed the alphabet, the `while` loop will recognize that and prompt again for different input.

Comment: @JohnGordon Oh yeah, I missed but isascii() is only working in python 3.7 and not the others, I should have first asked what version of python the asker used

Comment: This is the while loop objective, to force the user to use only numbers when typing

Comment: a1 = float(a.replace(',', '.'))

here's an even better version of the 'a' conversion to float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while` loop exits when an exclamation mark is entered, because it is ascii but it is not alphanumeric.

So then it goes to the next line and `float()` throws an error because `!` cannot be converted to a floating point number.

Perhaps you want this instead?

```
while not a.isdigit():
```

Comment: Thanks man, you just made a python programmer night happier :)